# Creating a custom rule in FxCop

Tags: .net, code-analysis, static-analysis, fxcop

I want to create extra rules in FXCop. Custom Rules to help ensure specific best practices like checking against inline sql.

I'm really looking for good resources and examples. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[This tutorial](http://www.binarycoder.net/fxcop/html/index.html) seems really comprehensive.

Comment: Can you please add some details from the article you are referring to? The link may get broken over time, and it would be useful if some details are available here as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the commercial tool [NDepend](http://www.NDepend.com) to write your [custom code rules over LINQ queries (CQLinq)](http://www.ndepend.com/Features.aspx#CQL). *Disclaimer: I am one of the developers of the tool*

More than [200 code rules](http://www.ndepend.com/DefaultRules/webframe.html) are proposed by default.

The strength of CQLinq over FxCop API or other tools, is that **it is straightforward to write a code rule**, and get *immediately* results. Facilities are proposed to browse matched code elements. For example:

[image: CQLinq code rule]

Answer (score 0):

The tutorial above is pretty good. I knocked together a sample VS project that also might be useful, since I couldn't find any example projects
http://www.doogal.co.uk/files/FxCopRules.zip