# vb.net Pass Textbox Between forms.

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have 2 forms. On Form1 I want to pass the textbox value to form 2 on load. This is what I thought would work. Form1 will be loaded and running and data will be populated in form1. I am exposing the property of the text box in form1. Then I am trying to use that exposed property in form2.

```
Public Class form1

Public ReadOnly Property GetTextBox() As String
    Get
        Return txtbox1.Value
    End Get
End Property
```

On form2

```
 Dim X As form1
 Me.TextBox1.Text = X.GetTextBox
```

Comment: `X` wont be a reference to the existing, open form1 instance

Comment: The textbox's value is 'Text', i.e. TextBox1.Text =

Comment: Well, to be sure of that I did a messagebox.show(GetSportsTextBox) on my form1 and it showed the correct value I was expecting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a handful of ways to skin this cat.

The simplest would be to create a second (or replace the existing) constructor for `Form2` that accepts a `string` as an parameter. Then when `Form1` creates `Form2` you can pass the argument that way.

```
Public Class Form2
    Sub New(ByVal txt As String)
        InitializeComponent()
        Me.TextBox1.Text = txt
End Sub
End Class
```

Then in `Form1` you'd have something like `Dim f2 As Form2 = New Form2(myTextBox.Text)`

The other ways are honestly basically the same as this, except you could pass the `Textbox` itself as an argument to the constructor, or even `Form1` and assign `Dim X As Form1 = theForm` in the constructor. Generally speaking, if you don't need anything more than just `Textbox.Text` then you should only accept a `string` in the constructor. No reason to expose an entire control or form if you don't need all of it!

Your current code is pretty close, but as Plutonix commented your `Form2`'s `X` property is just *another* instance of `Form1`, not the actual instance that's being displayed by the application.

Comment: I like your approach trying to keep it simple:

Comment: [KISS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) is often times a programmer's best friend

Comment: I like your approach trying to keep it simple. I tried the Sub New however I get some crazy error where my form 2 will not load.

Comment: @codeMonger123 Could you define "crazy error"? Did you include the second snippet of code that passes the string to `Form2` where you create it?

Answer (score 0):

VB will allow you to [refer to instances of forms by their class name](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6048889/11683), so you'd be able to use:

```
Me.TextBox1.Text = Form1.GetTextBox
```

However you should not rely on this and should instead pass an explicit instance of `Form1` to `Form2`, e.g. in a constructor:

```
' Form2
Public Sub New(ByVal f As Form1)
    Me.New()

    ' save 'f' for future reference
End Sub
```

Comment: Default form instances have been the cause so many hard to find bugs. Not only should you not rely on them, you should avoid using them at all IMHO.

Comment: This is the final code for form1 Dim pTextBox As String
        pTextBox = txtbox1.Value

        Dim frm As New frm2(pTextBox)
        frm.Show()

Answer (score 0):

When you do this:

```
Dim X As form1
```

You're create a *new* reference to a `form1`.  (And presumably instantiating it somewhere?  Or perhaps relying on [a feature in VB whereby a "default" form instance is used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4698538/why-is-there-is-a-default-instance-of-every-form-in-vb-net-but-not-in-c).  Which... don't do that.  Just trust me, don't.)  This instance is entirely unrelated to the instance that already exists.  What you're looking for is a reference to the instance that already exists.

If `form2` has a dependency on `form1` and requires a reference to an instance of `form1` then require that reference on the constructor for `form2`:

```
Private Property Form1Instance As form1

Sub New(ByVal form1Instance As form1)
    Me.Form1Instance = form1Instance
End Sub
```

When you create your instance of `form2`, provide it with a reference to the `form1` instance:

```
Dim form2Instance As New form2(Me)
form2Instance.Show()
```

Then within `form2` you can reference that existing instance of `form1`:

```
Dim someVariable As String = Me.Form1Instance.GetTextBox()
```

Comment: `Dim X As form1` Doesn't actually create a new instance as it lacks the `new` keyword.

Comment: @BradleyUffner: Good point.  I would then expect the OP's code to produce a `NullReferenceException`, unless there's something VB is doing behind the scenes with which I'm unfamiliar.  Either way, explicitly referencing a supplied instance is the way to go.

Comment: @David I believe the OP posted that bit for a pseudocode of how they roughly imagine it.

Comment: @BradleyUffner No, VB does not do that. A declared variable of type `Form1` will be `Nothing` as expected. You can however use the form's class name to access the default instance.