# How to create a form programatically vb.net

Tags: vb.net, forms

I am trying to create a form programatically from a existing form. Is there a way in which I can do it without inserting another form as a instance with just one form say form1 at runtime. I want to display the form with a populated checkboxes

Comment: You mean `Dim f = New Form1()`, or is about some complex templating scenario?

Comment: yeah something like that but I need form that is not an instance of form1, I want it like a completely new form. I just have one form : form1 in my solution explorer. I don't want to insert another form but create it and destroy that form in runtime

Comment: `Dim f = New Form1()` *is* a completely new form

Comment: You want a form that looks like Form1 but is not called Form1? Why? How is it different from [creating an instance](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6049062/11683) of Form1?

Comment: Its like drawing. Not the instance of first form.

Comment: If it is created " from a existing form" it is not "a completely new form".  What you want is not clear at all

Comment: Please click that link above @GowtamaKrishna. I have a feeling that you're not aware you could create different instances of the same Form class, as opposed to referring to a precreated instance by the class name in the VB6 style.

Comment: yes. different instance of same form works smooth. thanks. @GDerg

Comment: Dim f = New Form1() i can move forward from here @Plutonix. :)