# Define warnings for using properties (as attribute?) in C#

Tags: c#, attributes, warnings, obsolete

I want to raise warnings, if certain properties are used in the code. I could use the obsolete-attribute. But the used properties aren't obsolete, thus it wouldn't be that correct to give an obsolete warning.
How can I define own warnings for some properties that are printed during compilation, when the property is used?

Comment: Attributes are meta data - the obsolete attribute is one the compiler knows about and issues the warning. To get what you want, you will need to both create a custom attribute and built the tooling that will inspect the codebase for it and issue the warning.

Comment: not an answer because I'm not 90% sure you can get this done at compile time, but you can definitely [write your own FxCop rules](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/366095/creating-a-custom-rule-in-fxcop) that will do this sort of thing.

Comment: Found this in another thread, it may do the trick: 

http://stackoverflow.com/a/154254

Comment: FxCop or some other static analysis tool the way to go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Why not use the obsolete atrribute?
2. You can use task list with comments. Just use of the keywords defined here
   [image: VS2008 Options]
   [image: VS2008 Editor]

Comment: **Doh**. I know it is supposed to be `17*23` and not `17*24` but that is beyond the point for this posting.